# I have installed QtCharts module in Qt6, but iam receiving error

Tags: qt6, qtcharts

I want to use QtCharts in Qt6, i have installed the module, after that i have added the module in CMakeLists.txt, but iam receiving error (Qt6CoreMacros.cmake:559: error: Target "4-DonutChartExample" links to target "Qt6::Charts" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing? )

my CMakeLists.txt

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(4-DonutChartExample VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widget Charts)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        widget.cpp
        widget.h
        widget.ui
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(4-DonutChartExample
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
# Define target properties for Android with Qt 6 as:
#    set_property(TARGET 4-DonutChartExample APPEND PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR
#                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android)
# For more information, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-executable.html#target-creation
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(4-DonutChartExample SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
# Define properties for Android with Qt 5 after find_package() calls as:
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
    else()
        add_executable(4-DonutChartExample
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(4-DonutChartExample PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Charts)

set_target_properties(4-DonutChartExample PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(4-DonutChartExample)
endif()
```

Comment: I have the same problem, Did you find out what can we do?

Comment: yea you need to add the imported module in the second find_package() not first one